# Reading txt files in a choosen directory

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;     
  dp = opendir ("./");

  if (dp != NULL)
  {
    while (ep = readdir (dp))
      puts (ep->d_name);

    (void) closedir (dp);
  }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

  return 0;
}
```

This code gives me all things in that directory. It works like "ls" command. For example let's say i have one folder which is name is "folder" and one .txt file which is name is "input" (names are could be different btw) , in that directory. I want to decide if it is folder or txt file.If it is txt file how can i read it?

Comment: The `dirent` structure have a type-field. See e.g. [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). You can also use [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get more information about a "file". This only tells you if the "file" is an actual file, or a directory. There's is no way of knowing if a file is a "text" file or not, not really. Extensions (e.g. `.txt`) can give a hint, but it doesn't have to truthful. There are also many "text" files with other extensions.

Comment: `opendir()` returns NULL on error.   If the cause of the error is that the specified path is not a directory, `errno` is set to `ENOTDIR`.   If it is not a directory, attempt to open it for reading using standard IO functions.

Answer (score 1):

]You can use `scandir()` function to open and scan the entries in a directory.

The example comes from [man 3 scandir](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir)

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
/* print files in current directory in reverse order */
#include <dirent.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n;

    n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
    if (n < 0)
        perror("scandir");
    else {
        while (n--) {
            printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
            free(namelist[n]);
        }
        free(namelist);
    }
}
```

Note the `struct dirent`:

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
    off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
    unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
    unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                               by all file system types */
    char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
};
```

you can check if current entry is a regular file, directory or others by `d_type` field.

Available file types are :

```
#define DT_UNKNOWN       0
#define DT_FIFO          1
#define DT_CHR           2
#define DT_DIR           4   // directory type
#define DT_BLK           6
#define DT_REG           8   // regular file, txt file is a regular file
#define DT_LNK          10
#define DT_SOCK         12
#define DT_WHT          14
```

After checking the name and type of file, you can safely open it with `open()`(system call) or `fopen()`(glib function) and read the contents by `read()`(if you opened file via open() or `fread()`(fopen() counterpart).

DON'T forget to close file after read.

Besides, if you just want to check the existence and accessibility of a directory, `access()` is handle.

The code below tests if the dir exist.

```
int exist_dir (const char *dir)
{
    DIR *dirptr;

    if (access(dir, F_OK) != -1) {
        // file exists
        if ((dirptr = opendir(dir)) != NULL) {
            // do something here
            closedir (dirptr);
        } else {
            // dir exists, but not a directory
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        // dir does not exist
        return -1; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All information about a file except the contents can be get by calling function `stat`. `stat` has signature

```
int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *buf);
```

and returns information about the file in the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

`struct stat` encodes information of file type and file permission in the field `st_mode`.

Some additional macros are defined to test the file type:

> S_ISREG(m)  is it a regular file?
>
> S_ISDIR(m)  directory?
>
> S_ISCHR(m)  character device?
>
> S_ISBLK(m)  block device?
>
> S_ISFIFO(m) FIFO (named pipe)?
>
> S_ISLNK(m)  symbolic link?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
>
> S_ISSOCK(m) socket?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

Here is a piece of sample code:

```
stat(pathname, &sb);
if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) {
   /* Handle regular file */
}
```

As for reading, concatenate directory path and filename to get file path, using function `sprintf`, like this:

```
sprintf(file_path, "%s/%s", dir_path, file_name);
```